# Anemiaceae etymology

Tags: botany, taxonomy, etymology

What is the etymology of the name Anemiaceae for a family of ferns? I assume that it's from the name *Anemia* for one of its genera, but that is equally mysterious. Obviously it has no blood, but what fern does? I have been unable to find an answer by searching the internet.

Answer (score 2):

That one is Greek origin from [*aneimon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=igcARK7eX8oC&pg=PA115&lpg=PA115&dq=fern+aneimon&source=bl&ots=spkzrGh-H-&sig=ES2-Z2V7HHIvIbKbO94p0hO7cM0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwju2Mf6mufKAhXKuB4KHUvnDnYQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=fern%20aneimon&f=false) or "naked, unclad, without clothing" which is to refer to the panicles of the sporangia.